# How to skip/mark incomplete entire test suite in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

### Description

I have a *TestSuite* which I need to mark as skipped (the entire test suite - not the specific test cases within the suite).

```
class AllTests
{    
    public static function suite()
    {
        // this does not work same as within TestCase:
        // throw new \PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestError("Out of order");

        $Suite = new \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite(__NAMESPACE__);
        $Suite->addTestSuite(translators\AllTests::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlScopeTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlNsTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlElementTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlItemTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(LangCodeTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlElemClassTagTest::cls());
        return $Suite;
    }
}
```

As you can see throwing the `PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestError` exception does not work. It is not caught by the PHPUnit, and is breaks the execution as any uncaught exception (which is understandable, as the `suite()` method is invoked while building tests hierarchy, before actually running the tests).

I've seen an exception class named `PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestSuiteError`, but have no clue how to take advantage of it. Any ideas?

### Motivation

I have a *TestSuite*, which aggregates many test cases as well as other test suites. Almost every test in this fails, becouse of a change which I made in the core of my code.

The problem is that this package is not crutial, and is scheduled to be fixed later. Until then I have to run tests for every other package, but when I do the PHPUnit output becomes flooded with the errors coming from the package in question. This forces me to check every time if any of the failures is coming from any other package.

This, as you might suspect, is very susceptible to human error, i.e. I could miss a failure, which actually is important.

I could run only the test suite on which I am currently working, but I lose control of whether or not my changes in one package causes a failure in other package.

I do not want to comment out that test suite, because I'm afraid that I (or someone who will take over the code after me) could forget about it entirely.

Comment: Why don't you control that per the commandline parameters when you invoke PHPUnit? You can specify which suites to run and which not.

Comment: Because filtering out from command line is **filtering out**. This is not design to **mark** a test in any way. Two different concepts.

Comment: Not tests, suites. And not filtering out, just specifying the group of tests you want to execute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I'll put it together:

1. The `AllTests` class has to be refactored to extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite`.
2. This makes the class a fully valuable `TestSuite` and allows to implement a `setUp` method on the *suite* level.
3. The `setUp` method is called by the test runner (not by the builder), so it is safe to throw a `SkippedTestError` exception.
4. The corresponding method to do just that within a test suite is called [`markTestSuiteSkipped`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/91ba2757549feb69bdebbb2f13e5251046a1f256/src/Framework/TestSuite.php#L846) (notice the `Suite` in the method name).

The entire class would look like this:

```
class AllTests extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{    
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->markTestSuiteSkipped("zzz");
    }

    public static function suite()
    {
        $Suite = new self(__NAMESPACE__);
        $Suite->addTestSuite(translators\AllTests::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlScopeTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlNsTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlElementTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlItemTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(LangCodeTest::cls());
        $Suite->addTestSuite(TlElemClassTagTest::cls());
        return $Suite;
    }
}
```

The output is a pretty block of `S` letters, which definetly indicate, that we skipped a lot of tests. This cannot escape our attention and yet allows our tests to pass.

Answer (score 4):

You could [mark test as skipped](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests.examples.DatabaseTest.php).

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned I do not want to mark each _test case_ individually, but the entire _test suite_. There is a lot of unnecessary "copy/paste" involved if there are many test cases.

Comment: You could use setUp method for this.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. You were close, but not quite there. The `setUp` method has to be implemented in the `TestSuite`, so my `AllTests` class must be refactored to **extend** `PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase` instead of simply building the object in the `suite` method. And one final, important detail: the method to use is `markTestSuiteSkipped`, not `markTestSkipped`. Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I do not see a markTestSuiteSkipped method, whatsoever.

Comment: @Erik [here it is](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/91ba2757549feb69bdebbb2f13e5251046a1f256/src/Framework/TestSuite.php#L846)